# How can I have a Windows Service, installed using OctopusDeploy, use an app.config?

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

So far, I've been able to create a Windows Service, which I can then get TeamCity to build and pack up and make available for Octopus Deploy.

What I can't seem to do, is have an app.config which has a connection string in it and use that connection string.

The following is my Deploy.ps1:

```
# These variables should be set via the Octopus web portal:
#
#   ServiceName         - Name of the Windows service
# 
# sc.exe is the Service Control utility in Windows

# Default the service name
if (! $ServiceName)
{
    $ServiceName = "OctoService"
}

Write-Host "Service Name:" $ServiceName

# Get the exe name based ont the directory
$contentPath = (Join-Path $OctopusPackageDirectoryPath "content")
$configName = (Get-ChildItem $contentPath\*.config -Name | Select-Object -First 1)
$binPath  = (Join-Path $OctopusPackageDirectoryPath "lib\net40")
$exeName = (Get-ChildItem $binPath\*.exe -Name | Select-Object -First 1)
$fullPath = (Join-Path $binPath $exeName)
Write-Host "Service Path:" $fullPath

Write-Host "Config Path:" (Join-Path $contentPath $configName)
Copy-Item (Join-Path $contentPath $configName) $binPath

$service = Get-Service $ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (! $service)
{
    Write-Host "The service will be installed"
    New-Service -Name $ServiceName -BinaryPathName $fullPath -StartupType Automatic
}
else
{
    Stop-Service $ServiceName -Force

    $fullPath = Resolve-Path $fullPath
    & "sc.exe" config "$ServiceName" binPath= $fullPath start= auto | Write-Host

    Start-Service $ServiceName
}
```

Here's my .nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2012</copyright>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="app.config" target="content" />
    <file src="Deploy.ps1" />
  </files>  
</package>
```

If I try to access ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"], I'll get a null reference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My guess is that it's because I'm not using OctoPack, so this whole deal with having files in the nuget directories (lib, content, etc) isn't right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my money is on you needing to name your app.config to exename.exe.config so it is picked up by your service.

App.config is the 'temporary' name used in the ide, it gets renamed as part of the build to whatever the exe name is

Comment: I'll try that, let you know shortly.

Comment: Bingo, that's it exactly. Looks like using the Rename-Item cmdlet might let me automate that as well. The following, was the new command I added to make this work:

    Rename-Item (Join-Path $binPath $configName) ($exeName + ".config")